# Syntax in function's parameters in documentation

Tags: php, syntax, documentation

Can you please explain documentation syntax in functions. For example php function

```
int preg_match ( string $pattern , string $subject [, array &$matches [, int $flags = 0 [, int $offset = 0 ]]] )
```

So far i understand that in in round brackets goes function's parameters,also that square bracket means for array. But what does that mean    `[,`
and why there are no comma after $subject?

Comment: [Documentation of how to read documentation.](http://php.net/manual/en/about.prototypes.php)

Comment: If you want a real challenge then check out the function definition for [array_diff_uassoc()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-uassoc.php)

Comment: `[]` in php documentation (and in many other docs) is used to specify optionnal parameters, this has nothing to do with arrays

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The arguments that are inside `[]` are optional. The `[,` means that if you want to specify the arguments after that you must add the `,`. In the use of the function, you don't have to write `[]`.

Also you don't have to specify the type of each parameter, it's shown in the documentation to make you know what you have to pass.

Arguments that contain a `=` in the documentation are usually optional, and the value after the equal in the documentation means the default value.

Comment: '*are usually optional*' - They *are* optional, not *usually*.

Answer (score 1):

That is just how PHP documents optional arguments.  You don't use brackets for those.

So you would only need to provide the $pattern and $subject and can optionally provide a reference array for $matches, an integer for $flags, and an integer for $offset.

If you don't provide the optional arguments, you wouldn't have a comma after $subject, hence why the comma is in the brackets.

Comment: thank you for the answer, but why do they nested here, while in practice they used one by one?

Comment: My internet went out while I was adding more details.   My edit should cover more.

Comment: @MarkAmbrazhevich That makes each one optional. If it was `[, array &$matches, int $flags]` then using one would require the use of the second. However, I do not recall any functions which do this...

Answer (score 1):

Here, the square brackets have nothing to do with arrays, they mean that the parameters are optional.

More info about how to read a function definition in the PHP doc can be found here: http://php.net/manual/en/about.prototypes.php